# Disposing DbContext inside Service's dispose method

Tags: servicestack

I have following code in my service. I get the following error when i make a request to `GET /posts`

***The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed***

How should I dispose the DbContext here? Can i not use Service's Dispose method here OR in what cases can i use it for?

```
public class PostsService : ServiceStack.Service
{
    BlogDbContext db = new BlogDbContext();

    public object Get(GetAllPosts req)
    {
        return db.Posts;
    }

    public override void Dispose()
    {
        if (db != null)
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }

        base.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Can't reproduce:

Unfortunately I can't reproduce your issue, my simple test following your dispose pattern succeeded.

I created a dummy `BlogDbContext`:

```cs
public class BlogDbContext : IDisposable
{
    public void DummyMethod()
    {
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Disposing BlogDbContext");
    }
}
```

Then I implemented a test service like your `PostsService`:

```cs
[Route("/Test", "GET")]
public class TestRequest : IReturnVoid {}

public class TestController : Service
{
    BlogDbContext db = new BlogDbContext();

    public void Get(TestRequest request)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Request use BlogDbContext");
        db.DummyMethod();
        Console.WriteLine("Finished using BlogDbContext");
    }

    public override void Dispose()
    {
        if(db != null)
            db.Dispose();

        base.Dispose();
    }
}
```

When I call the `/Test` route, no exception is thrown and the console outputs:

- Request use BlogDbContext
- Finished using BlogDbContext
- Disposing BlogDbContext

This would indicate to me that there is an issue in your `BlogDbContext` not staying around long enough to be used. Does your `BlogDbContext` stay alive if you don't dispose in the service?

---

### Dependancy Injection

If I were implementing the service I would take advantage of ServiceStack's dependancy injection *([See here for more information](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/The-IoC-container))* and inject the database instance into your service using your AppHost configure method. When the request ends it will automatically call your `BlogDbContext`'s `Dispose` method. So you don't need to implement the `override void Dispose` in your service. *It's easier than it sounds.*

In you AppHost, add to your Configure method:

```cs
public override void Configure(Funq.Container container)
{
    // This injects your Database Context, a fresh context for each request
    container.Register<BlogDbContext>(c => new BlogDbContext()).ReusedWithin(Funq.ReuseScope.None);
}
```

In your Service replace

```cs
BlogDbContext db = new BlogDbContext();
```

with

```cs
public BlogDbContext db { get; set; }
...
// Remember to remove the: public override void Dispose()
```

It also makes your code easier to Mock in testing.

If you still find it is failing this way, then there is definitely something not right with your `BlogDbContext`.